# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Parenting Stack Exchange](http://parenting.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What do you say when your child says "You're mean!"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10879/what-do-you-say-when-your-child-says-youre-mean)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to help a tomboy not dread puberty](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10748/how-to-help-a-tomboy-not-dread-puberty)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [When a child only gets enthused about books above his reading level](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/when-a-child-only-gets-enthused-about-books-above-his-reading-level)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How fast does the prenatal swimming reflex disappear?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10727/how-fast-does-the-prenatal-swimming-reflex-disappear)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What are some good natural teethers?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10824/what-are-some-good-natural-teethers)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's a good way to encourage a toddler to blow their nose?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10777/whats-a-good-way-to-encourage-a-toddler-to-blow-their-nose)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to break the cycle of lies?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10969/how-to-break-the-cycle-of-lies)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [5 yr old son behaving sexually](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10712/5-yr-old-son-behaving-sexually)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Two year old still takes a bottle of milk before bedtime, should I wean her from the bottle and the milk?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10739/two-year-old-still-takes-a-bottle-of-milk-before-bedtime-should-i-wean-her-from)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Nursing an infant while being pregnant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10923/nursing-an-infant-while-being-pregnant)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 5)

---